# D3 "pinning" a tick to a bar value in a chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am struggling trying to solve a problem with setting the yAxis tick marks so that I can "pin" a tick to a specific value. Please bear with my explanation, I will likely butcher the d3 terminology...

First, I am using this [Grouped bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad) example as my reference, so please refer to that also.

Here is an image that more or less shows what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: s]

I want to make the y scale a percentage, and make "12" (red line) display "100%" (as a label?) and pin that to the value of the gray bar. The other ticks would be labelled as percentages also, with a linear scale (10%, 20%, etc). As the data will change, the y axis values will also change and the "100%" label will need to always align with the data corresponding to the gray bar value.

Think of this as a reference value that I can then compare the other bars to, and those bars can exceed 100%.

I am not sure of this is helpful, but the code that sets the y domain in question is as follows:

```js
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);
```

How can I accomplish my goal?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the y scale you pass to yAxis maps your data values to svg dimensions.

data -> svg dimensions.

If you notice the yAxis labels its ticks with the actual data values, or the domain of the scale you give it.

So all you need to do is pass it a scale with percentage in its domain that goes to svg dimensions: 
percentage -> svg dimensions

Here are two ways you can do that.

1) First convert the data to percentages and then make the scale. Then you use this scale for plotting and passing to the axis.

2) Leave the plotting alone and create a third scale that maps 
percentage -> height and just pass this to yAxis. Notice this works because the scales are both linear.

Modifying the example you referenced I used the second method. I pasted the code for completeness and highlighted the part I modified. Note I made the "medium value" (grey bar) in the Student set 100%.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);



var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .tickSize(0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#ca0020","#f4a582","#d5d5d5","#92c5de","#0571b0"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {

  var categoriesNames = data.map(function(d) { return d.categorie; });
  var rateNames = data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; });



    //=========================================================================
    //=========================================================================
    // Modified code here 
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //data -> percent - using the Student value of Medium to set to 100% 
    let dataToPercent = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain( [0, data[0].values.filter( d => d.rate === "Medium" )[0].value] )
        .range( [ 0, 100 ] )


    // percent -> height
    // Third scale just to pass to yAxis
    let percentToHeight = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain( [0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { 
            return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { 
                return dataToPercent( d.value ); //only change is dataToPercent( d.value ) versus original return of d.value
            })
        })])
        .range( [ height, 0] )

  // set the yAxis with our new scale - use tickFormat to add percentage sign
  yAxis
    .scale( percentToHeight )
    .tickFormat( d => d + "%" )

//add the red line
svg.append( "line" )
    .attr( "x1", 0 )
    .attr( "y1", percentToHeight( 100 ))
    .attr( "x1", width ) 
    .attr( "y2", percentToHeight( 100 ))
    .attr( "stroke", "red" )
    .attr( "stroke-width", "2px" )
  //===========================================================================
  //===========================================================================
  // End modified code 
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  x0.domain(categoriesNames);
  x1.domain(rateNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .style('opacity','0')
      .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style('font-weight','bold')
      .text("Value");

  svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity','1');

  var slice = svg.selectAll(".slice")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(0); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
      });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function (d) {return Math.random()*1000;})
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  //Legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; }).reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity","0");

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) {return d; });

  legend.transition().duration(500).delay(function(d,i){ return 1300 + 100 * i; }).style("opacity","1");

});




</script>
```

This sets the 100% to the first grey bar, but you could extend this set each grey bar as 100% for its associated values, and then make the xaxis update on hover or something.

As to the red line, just append it to the svg (or any g element) with `d3.append` and modify its position as appropriate.